# Importing Files in Typescript outside of 'rootDir'

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have a project that has the following file structure

```bash
project
|
├── App1/static/App1
|   ├── ts
|   ├── js
|   └── tsconfig.json
|
├── App2/static/App2
|   ├── ts
|   ├── js
|   └── tsconfig.json
|
├── App3/static/App3
|   ├── ts
|   ├── js
|   └── tsconfig.json
|
└── tsconfig.json
```

Each app needs the compiled Typescript files found in the `ts` directory to go into each of the `js` folders found in the same directory. To make this work so far, I have a global `tsconfig.json` file found at the top of the "project" directory. Then, the `tsconfig.json` file found inside of each app has the following configuration:

```json
{
    "extends": "../../../tsconfig.json",    // Path to global tsconfig.json
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "js",                     // Where the transpiled Javascript files go
        "rootDir": "ts",                    // Where the Typescript files are
    },
}
```

Then, when I run `tsc -p App1/static/App1`, for example, the Typescript files inside of App1's `ts` folder get compiled and placed inside of the `js` folder. Everything okay so far.

Now, my problem is that sometimes App1 needs files from App3, so I do an import similar to this one:

```js
// App1/static/App1/test.ts
import { module } from "../../../../App3/static/App3/ts/module.js"
```

This works, however, I get the following warning on the import: `error TS6059: File 'module.js' is not under 'rootDir' '/ts/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.`

What changes can I apply to the `tsconfig.json` file in App1 to make this work. I have tried adding the `../../../App3/static/App3/ts` folder as a `rootDir` in my config (by using `rootDirs`) but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reference each subproject in the package.json file

```
// App1 package.json:
{
    "dependencies": {
        "app2": "../App2/static/App2",
        "app3": "../App3/static/App3",
    }
}
```

Now you can reference the other apps as external packages

`import { module } from "app3/js/module.js"`

Import the compiled JavaScript, not source typescript.

I'm not 100% sure whether you need to fiddle around with import/export settings, but this should get you 90% of the way there.

You may also need to set "declaration": true in the tsconfig of each subproject, so that .d.ts files are created in the build folders.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `compilerOptions.rootDir` key from `tsconfig.json` of `app1`

```
{
    "extends": "../../../tsconfig.json",    // Path to global tsconfig.json
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "js",                     
    },
}
```

Comment: This more or less works, however, it causes the `js` folder to have a subfolder with the following structure: `App1/static/App1/ts` which contains all the compiled files found inside of the `ts` folder. So the full route to the compiled files looks like this: `App1/static/App1/js/App1/static/App1/ts`. I would like for the scripts to simply be placed inside the js folder without the additional `App1/static/App1/ts` first.

Comment: The longer file structure makes actually sense, since files with the same name from App1 and App2 cannot be in the same ts folder. Also, having `App1/static/App1/js/conpiledFileFromApp1.js` and `App1/static/App1/js/App2/static/App2/ts` is a strange combination that doesn't make sense.